# How to use update trigger to update another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

I am new to triggers and want to create a trigger on an update of a column and update another table with that value.

I have table1 with a year column and if the application updates that year column I need to update table 2 with the year the same year.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_UpdateAnnualYear]
   ON  [dbo].[table1]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

if (UPDATE (intAnnualYear))   
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    Update table2 set AnnualYear = intAnnualYear where table2.ID = table1.ID
END
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't reference `table1` inside the trigger. Use the `inserted` pseudo table to get the "after" values. Also remember that an update can affect multiple rows.

So replace your current `update` statement with

```
UPDATE table2
SET    table2.annualyear = inserted.intannualyear
FROM   table2
       JOIN inserted
         ON table2.id = inserted.id
```

Answer (score 9):

You only need to update the records in table2 if the column intannualyear is involved.  Also, this is an alternative UPDATE syntax across two tables from what Martin has shown

```
IF UPDATE(intannualyear)
    UPDATE table2
    SET    annualyear = inserted.intannualyear
    FROM   inserted
    WHERE table2.id = inserted.id
```

Comment: Thank you worked great. Just for clarification for other people just starting out with triggers I found a good article to explain the inserted table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457013/cascade-on-delete-or-use-triggers), if there's only one "downstream" table then another option with a properly defined foreign key relation would be Cascaded update.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the above answers, if you have to check more than one column you can use a INNER JOIN between inserted and deleted, or several UPDATE() calls:

```
IF ( UPDATE(Col1) OR UPDATE(Col2) ) BEGIN ...
```