# How to write trigger to update row in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EventsCnfig
(
Id int,
InspectionId int,
Event int
);
```

And this:

```
CREATE TABLE Inspections
(
Id int,
IsRepaired Bit
);
```

`InspectionId` in `EventsCnfig` table is foreign key of `Inspections` table with relation of one to many.

Here is SQL [plunker](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08a45/1)

I need to create trigger when any row in `EventsCnfig` table updated the value of the column `Event`  to -1 or inserted new row with the `Event` value -1 the row in `Inspections` table with appropriate `Id` has to update IsRepaired value in column to 1(true).

How can I write the trigger to implement the desired logic?

Comment: Write the trigger as best you can and we will help.what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write **two** triggers - one for `UPDATE`, another for `INSERT` - if you try to do this in a single trigger, the code gets messy because of the checks for "is this an INSERT or UPDATE operation?" etc. - don't do that....

`AFTER UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TrgEventsConfigUpdate
ON dbo.EventsConfig
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    UPDATE insp
    SET IsRepaired = 1
    FROM dbo.Inspections insp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.InspectionId = insp.Id
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.Id = i.Id
    WHERE i.[Event] = -1 AND d.[Event] <> -1
```

Basically, after an update, you need to look at the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables which contain the updated rows - if the *new* row (after the update) has a value of -1, while the *old* row (before the update) did not --> then the column `Event` has been *updated* to -1 and thus the `IsRepaired` in the table `Inspections` needs to be set to `1` (true).

`AFTER INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TrgEventsConfigInsert
ON dbo.EventsConfig
AFTER INSERT
AS 
    UPDATE insp
    SET IsRepaired = 1
    FROM dbo.Inspections insp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.InspectionId = insp.Id
    WHERE i.[Event] = -1
```

Same idea - just a bit simpler, since there's no "old" row to compare to: if the column in the list of inserted rows has a value of -1, then update the `Inspections` table for those `InspectionId` values to be `1`.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the  answer. In SQL fiddle when I try to create insert and update triggers I get error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.
I tryed  END;  but still I get error.So any idea how can I create multiple triggers in sql fiddle?

Comment: @Michael: you might need a `GO` between the two

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read all about triggers:

[How to use update trigger to update another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252802/how-to-use-update-trigger-to-update-another-table)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

There should be more than enough information to build the trigger by yourself. 
If you have a "finished" trigger that does not work the way you want, you can post it here and the community will help you out.