# How to link one row to a row on another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a little odd situation here and I'm not going to be able to alter the database structure so please don't mention that.

I have two tables called users and forum_users.
'users' table has two rows: user_id (primary), username.
'forum_users' table has three rows: id (primary), forum_user_id, forum_username.

Say we have a user with user_id of '23'. This user is already automatically added to forum_users table with id of '1', forum_user_id of '23', and a random forum_username.
What I want to accomplish is, I want 'forum_username' data to update to 'username' data of the entry where 'user_id' is equal to 'forum_user_id'.

How do I go about accomplishing this? Can this be done through only MySQL without using any kind of external script? If not then how I go about making such script?

Sample database: http://pastebin.com/ZYf8baV3

Here's a quick Paint drawing of what I need:
[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Duy.png)

Comment: Please show what you are trying to explain with sample data and expected results.  I can't follow what you're trying to describe.

Comment: I wasn't asked, I'm just working on a project with little unusual requirements. It's not a forum, I just used that name as placeholder.

Comment: So you want the username in the users table to update whenever an update is made to the username in the forum_users table?

Comment: I want forum_username in forum_users table to update to username in users table whenever a new entry is added to forum_users table.

Comment: My bet is that @HikJ wants to replicate data on a phpBB forum into another database. That is why he can't change the structure. Why not edit the phpBB function called on username changes so it edits on both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Trigger

The MySQL trigger is a database object that is associated with a table. It will be activated when a defined action is executed for the table. The trigger can be executed when you run one of the following MySQL statements on the table: INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. It can be invoked before or after the event.

Quick Example using the data you provided:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CasscadeUsername_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON Users FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE forum_users
SET forum_username = username
WHERE forum_users.user_id = users.user_id

END
```

Here is a link to a tutorial [trigger-syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: I agree with this solution. You should create a trigger on forum_users. On an update, make it update the line on users to make it equal.

Comment: This question is pretty good [How to use update trigger to update another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252802/how-to-use-update-trigger-to-update-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

To update all the records of user with corresponding username of forum_user, try using the below code

```
 update user a
    set username = (select forum_user_name  from forum_user b 
where b.forum_user_id=a.user_id);
```

To update only for a single record, say 23, use the below update statement

```
update user a
set username = (select forum_user_name  from forum_user b
 where b.forum_user_id=23)
where user_id=23;
```