# What is the proper way to compute attributes in a table based on other attributes in other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

Lets have for example two tables: Table A and Table B which are in JOIN.

Table A:

```
id INT PK
attr1 INT
```

Table B:

```
id INT PK
table_A_id INT NOT NULL FK
attr1 INT
attr2 INT
```

**Table B** `attr2` is computed as `TableB.attr2 = TableA.attr1 * TableB.attr1`.

The requirement is the following:

- If a new record is inserted into **Table B** or an existing record is updated where the **Table B** `attr1` changes the **Table B** `attr2` must be calculated/recalculated.
- If **Table A** `attr1` is changed then corresponding **Table B** `attr2` should be recalculated.

So I am dealing with dependency between attributes in computation.

What is the proper way to perform the calculations in MSSql? Maybe triggers?

Comment: My first thought would just have a view with the calculated column, if the join isn't too expensive. Let the view worry about sync. If that's not an option, yeah, triggers. The inserted/deleted objects will come in to play https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver16 . And seems like a similar problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252802/how-to-use-update-trigger-to-update-another-table

Comment: View is not an option because the computations and the dependencies in our case in DB are far more complex than in the example.

Comment: A view works even if the computation is much more complex so it would be my recommendation too, I think there is almost always a way to optimize it using views. If you really want triggers it can work, but I wouldn't recommend it for something like that since it might cost you in performance in multiple places if the table is used often or for batch update/delete/insert.

Comment: With your current table structure, I believe you will need to implement triggers on both tables - An `AFTER UPDATE` on Table A, and an `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` on Table B. Each trigger should check to see if the Attr1 value actually changed, and if so, calculate the new Attr2 value. The Table A trigger would need to recalculate and update all related Table B attr2 values. When creating triggers, be sure to use set logic instead of scalar logic in case the trigger is fired after multiple rows were added or updated.

Comment: Have you considered creating a table valued function for this instead of storing the computed value in your database? You would just need to adjust your queries to use a cross apply to your function when you need that value.

Comment: Unless you give us more reasons why a view wouldn't work then that will be what we would recommend. You need to give us a more precise example showing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use triggers to automatically perform calculations or actions when certain events occur, such as the insertion or update of records. For your specific case, you can use an AFTER INSERT, UPDATE trigger on TableB to recalculate attr2 based on the conditions you provided.

Example  code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_TableB_UpdateAttr2
ON TableB
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(attr1) OR UPDATE(attr2)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE b
        SET attr2 = a.attr1 * b.attr1
        FROM TableB b
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON b.id = i.id
        INNER JOIN TableA a ON b.table_A_id = a.id;
    END
END;
```